# need to list the item from facts output

Tags: ansible

I need to save the target host's IP addresses to a file using set_fact. Below is my playbook, but it's giving output as a list.

```
  hosts:  all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        data:  "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
    - set_fact:
        ip: "{{ data.split(',')  }}"

    - name: Show the devices
      shell: echo {{ item }} >> /tmp/ips
      with_items: "{{  ip  }}"
```

output:
ok: [system1] => {
    "data": [
        "172.19.0.1",
        "172.18.0.1",
        "172.20.0.1",
        "172.17.0.1",
        "172.16.108.124",
        "10.0.41.117"
    ]
}

```
cat /tmp/ips
[u'172.19.0.1', u'172.18.0.1', u'172.20.0.1', u'172.17.0.1', u'172.16.108.124', u'10.0.41.117']


Desired o/p is 
 172.168.1.21
 172.168.1.22
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
shell: echo {{ item }} >> /tmp/ips
with_items: "{{  ip  }}"
```

Use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html).

```
template:
  src: ips.j2
  dest: /tmp/ips
```

with template ips.j2

```
{% for item in ip %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ansible_all_ipv4_addresses` is already an array so you don't need to `split` it:

```
- copy:
    dest: /tmp/ips
    content: "{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | join('\n') }}"
```

This will produce the desired output.